# Updating Excel sheet with +1 or -1 in column 'stock'

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYdak.jpg I am loading a excel file into a datagridview with this code

```
private void Loadexcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog importexcel = new OpenFileDialog();
        importexcel.Filter = "Excel files | *.xlsx";
        if (importexcel.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            filetextBox.Text = importexcel.FileName;

        String connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filetextBox.Text + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connStr);
        string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]";
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, conn);
        DataTable dT = new DataTable();
        
        conn.Open();
        try
        {
            OleDbDataReader dR = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            dT.Load(dR);
            excelviewgrid.DataSource = dT;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)

        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
            NewOrder.Enabled = true;
        }
    
        
    }
```

i am adding items to my listbox with a textboxinput from the user that should match the Material number which adds the information from material description column and some extra hardcoded text. and also loops the input to the amount input in the combobox. so far this all works.

```
private void textBoxInput_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            string strCurrentString = textBoxInput.Text.Trim().ToString();

            if (strCurrentString != "")
            {
                if (radioButtonPick.Checked == true && radioButtonNew.Checked == true)
                {
                    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in excelviewgrid.Rows)
                    {
                        if (textBoxInput.Text == row.Cells["Material"].Value.ToString())
                        {
                            int value = Convert.ToInt32(comboBoxmultiply.Text);
                            for (int i = 0; i < value; i++)
                            {
                                listBoxinput.Items.Add(textBoxInput.Text + " | " + row.Cells["Material Description"].Value + " (-1 New Pick)");
                            }
                            comboBoxmultiply.SelectedIndex = 0;
                            textBoxInput.Clear();

                        }

                    }

                }
            }
```

but now i want to make it that for each item on the listbox https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpC0w.jpg it updates the stock column by +1 or -1 depending on pick or receive(this is done with using the right event trigger(if radiobuttonxxx == true) and throw an error if going below 0

```
 private void buttontest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filetextBox.Text + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connStr);

        conn.Open();
        OleDbCommand ojbCmdSelect = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE [sheet1$] set [Stock] = [Stock] + 1 where [Material] = 114-6776");
        ojbCmdSelect.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
    }
```

FIXED look further
I tried this code with a test button and just the material from one item(this needs to be changed to every item on the listbox) on the excel list.

but it throws me a error "System.InvalidOperationException: 'ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property was not initialized.'"

EDIT:
the connection issue seems to be fixed with this code
EDIT:2 massively improved and corrected by Cetin Basoz (look below)

```
conn.Open();
        string strSQL = "UPDATE [sheet1$] set Stock = stock+1 where Material = '114-6776'";
        OleDbCommand ojbCmdSelect = new OleDbCommand(strSQL,conn);
        ojbCmdSelect.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
```

now i need to figure out how i can make the "where material = listboxitems"

EDIT: 3 also provided by Cetin Basoz(look below)

I am new to coding so no experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the message says, ojbCmdSelect needs a connection and you didn't set it. Also if you pass that, there is another error in the OleDbCommand text itself. You should use parameters and you could do the update single or in a loop. ie:

```
private void buttontest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filetextBox.Text + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
    using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connStr))
    using (OleDbCommand ojbCmdSelect = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE [sheet1$] set [Stock] = [Stock] + 1 where [Material] = @material", conn))
    { 
        ojbCmdSelect.Parameters.Add("@material", OleDbType.VarChar);
        
    
        conn.Open();
        // this part could be in a loop
        // for ... {
        ojbCmdSelect.Parameters["@material"].Value = "114-6776";
        ojbCmdSelect.ExecuteNonQuery();
        // }
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

EDIT: As per the listbox.items, you are adding items to listbox with their code appended extra space | and then description. You first need to get the code per listbox item:

```
private void buttontest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filetextBox.Text + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
    using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connStr))
    using (OleDbCommand ojbCmdSelect = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE [sheet1$] set [Stock] = [Stock] + 1 where [Material] = @material", conn))
    { 
        ojbCmdSelect.Parameters.Add("@material", OleDbType.VarChar);
        
    
        conn.Open();
        foreach (string item in listBoxinput.Items)
        {
            var itemcode = item.Split('|')[0].Trim();
            ojbCmdSelect.Parameters["@material"].Value = itemcode;
            ojbCmdSelect.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

PS: In a real world application, instead of having such items in a listbox, you would want to bind it to an object where it has Id and the display text at least. Splitting from a long string to get the Id is not feasible at all times.

Comment: You are correct that i forgot to add the connection. this indeed did fix that issue.
now this is example code what i really want is to make every item that is added to the itemlist to update its stock with +1. I am not familiar with the parameters. ill do some more research about those. Anyway you were already a big help.

Comment: @Duivelbryan, it was not only connection, SQL update was also wrong. You should always use parameters and I also added code to loop listboxInput.Items.

Comment: I got to ask do you have a good place to learn about parameters? How to set them up and how they work? You code does exactly what i want it to do but i also want to understand why.

Comment: @Duivelbryan, well it is in documentation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0 for OleDbCommand and you can also look at places like SqlCommand, SqlParameter ... The sample code above shows how to set them up (actually in documentation setting them up is less obvious than this sample - but I must admit it shows using ? which is right for OleDbParameters. ).